# Git make formatting changes without commit

Tags: git

I'm in a bit of a strange situation. I have a repo that I work on using different computers. Vscode on one computer was configured to use spaces where one was configured to use tabs. This looked fine in the IDE but the code on github looks terrible because of this.

It's easy enough to go back and change spaces to tabs but I do not want this change to be part of my commit history going forward. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you don't want it in the commit log, you need to rewrite history so those commits "were always" correct. This will change the hashes and be a pain to update for any copies of the repository you have checked out. I'm pretty sure you can do this relatively easily with [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), specifically the `--tree-filter` part, using `sed` and `find`, but I've never used `git filter-branch` so I don't know the specifics.

Comment: To avoid this sort of thing in the future, you can create an [EditorConfig file](https://editorconfig.org/) and install [the VSCode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig).

Comment: @DanielH I'm the only one working on the repo at the moment so I don't have much of an issue with rewriting history. I'll look into filter branch. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bit of a work around. You can create a `.editorconfig` file in the repo and tell github how you would like it to display tabs. The following was enough to make everything consistent

```
root = true 

[*]
indent_style = tab 
indent_size = 4
```